# calling the static method in main class using reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, static-methods

this program recover the 2 group of the numbers from user that it compare then if  the first one is bigger pointA receive one grade if not pointB receive one grade and it continues until last number.my problem is that i can't print the final result which the grade for pointA,pointB because of static method that i have in program.how can i print it there by using reflection
or any other method?

```html
public class Solution {
    static int[] solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2){
      int pointA=0;
   int pointB=0;
        int FristArray[]={a0,a1,a2};
        int scoundArray[]={b0,b1,b2};
        for(int x=0;x<=FristArray.length;x++) 
        for(int y=0;x<=scoundArray.length;y++) 
            if (x>y){ 
                pointA+=1;
            }
        else if(x<y){  
            pointB+=1;
        }
       int points[]={pointA,pointB};
       return  points; 
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a0 = in.nextInt();
        int a1 = in.nextInt();
        int a2 = in.nextInt();
        int b0 = in.nextInt();
        int b1 = in.nextInt();
        int b2 = in.nextInt();
        int[] result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              System.out.print(result[i]+"i want to print it here");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is an infinite loop.  Have a careful look at the inner loop in `solve`: `for(int y=0;x<=scoundArray.length;y++) `

Comment: And what does `static` have to do with it? And what makes you think Reflection will solve it?

Comment: method solve is static,i think that's reason i can print what this method return.

Comment: i thought maybe Reflection can help me but i don't know how

Comment: I can see that it's static for myself, thank you. What I can't see is why you think that's relevant. It is in fact *not* a *problem* but a *requirement* for the method to be called in the way you are calling it. You haven't answered my question about Reflection. Your own question continues to make absolutely no sense whatsoever. You haven't described an actual problem, and you haven't given any reasons for your guesswork about it.

Comment: What will help you is a little bit of debugging.  You will see that `solve` never finishes. I refer you to my earlier comment for a hint as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the second loop: not

```
for(int y=0;x<=scoundArray.length;y++)
```

but

```
for(int y=0;y<=scoundArray.length;y++)
```

change x to y

```
 public class Solution {

             static int[] solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2){
                  int pointA=0;
               int pointB=0;
                    int FristArray[]={a0,a1,a2};
                    int scoundArray[]={b0,b1,b2};
                    for(int x=0;x<=FristArray.length;x++) 
                    for(int y=0;y<=scoundArray.length;y++) 
                        if (x>y){ 
                            pointA+=1;
                        }
                    else if(x<y){  
                        pointB+=1;
                    }
                   int points[]={pointA,pointB};
                   return  points; 
                }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the values : (Master rsl)");
                int a0 = in.nextInt();
                int a1 = in.nextInt();
                int a2 = in.nextInt();
                int b0 = in.nextInt();
                int b1 = in.nextInt();
                int b2 = in.nextInt();
                int[] result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2);
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                      System.out.print(result[i]+ " " +i+ " want to print it here");
                }
                System.out.println("");


        }

    }
```

Comment: that was the mistake,i change it but still i have error in the line  that i try to print it,how i try to print the result is static.solve-error is  illegal start of expression